# Service Cloud API With Professional Licence

Tags: api, professional-edition

I am currently using Salesforce Service Cloud with a Lightning Professional licence.

I wish to be able to use the Salesforce API to withdraw information from Salesforce. However after looking into this on the website I have found that the licence I have cannot use the APIs.

> 'To use SOAP API, your organization must use Enterprise Edition, Performance Edition, Unlimited Edition, or Developer Edition.'

Is there anyway I can access the API functionality without having to upgrade to the Lightning Enterprise licence which is double the price per user?

Update: I have read that there used to be an option of an additional add-on for the API functionality to be available with Professional Licence, is this still available? If so what is the additional cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of June 2017 the list price we paid to add API access to a Professional version is $300/year/existing-license (minus a volume discount.) So if you have 10 users, that's $3000/year added to your existing bill (even if only 1 user ever uses the API, you pay for everyone.)

Talk with your representative for more details. Your results may vary since they don't actually advertise offering that product anywhere, but I've seen other reports online of people also paying $300/license/year and our rep immediately knew that product offering and price when I mentioned it. So I have a feeling this is not an uncommon thing for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the limited [Excel Connector Professional Edition API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Excel_Connector) if you're willing to use Excel, but for "serious" integration work, you will need to upgrade.